# How to forbid gridster to move widget element down

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget, gridster

All board is filled by widgets, without margin. And when i try to move element from one column(1) to another(2) the elements at column 2 just go down out of the board like:

[image: errormovewidget]

I'd like to forbid placing a widget to a place if there is no place for widgets in the column.

My code:

```
   gridster = $(".gridster > ul").gridster({

          widget_margins: [mySizeDetector.blockMargin, mySizeDetector.blockMargin], 
          widget_base_dimensions: [mySizeDetector.dx, mySizeDetector.dy], /*[width, height]*/
          min_cols: mySizeDetector.xCount,
          min_rows: mySizeDetector.yCount,
  }).data('gridster');
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can restrict it go in **x-axis** beyond the container, but not in **y-axis**.

Because we have `min_cols` and `max_cols` to restrict it in **x-axis**. But we have only min_rows **but not** `max_rows`.

You can refer the documentation: http://gridster.net/#documentation

Answer (score -1):

have a look at the [gridster fork](https://github.com/dustmoo/gridster.js) by Dustin Moore. Download the .js and the .css File.

Excerpt form the link:

Widgets of smaller or equal size to the dragged widget (player) will swap places with the original widget.

This causes tiles to swap left and right as well as up and down.

By default smaller players will shift larger widgets down.

I have added an option to prevent this behavior:

```
    $.gridster({
        shift_larger_widgets_down: false
    });
```